# Using ProxyPass with AWS ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, proxy

I have a very basic deployment that works (roughly) like so:

`WebServer ELB -> WebServer -> AppServer ELB -> AppServer -> RDS instances`.

1. All requests from the webserver are forwarded to the AppServerELB over port 80.
2. The AppServerELB takes these requests and forwards them to an AppServer instance. `virtualhost.conf` then routes these requests to the appropriate port internally.

Issues:
1. Session stickiness is lost. Completely. `ProxyPass` is configured on the WebServers like so:

```
ProxyPass /xyz http://elbDNSName/xyz
ProxyPassReverse /xyz http://elbDNSName/xyz
```

And on the application servers, `virtualhost.conf` looks something like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
JkMount /xyz* tomcat1
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `tomcat1` is in turn defined in `workers.properties`.

2. Session stickiness was maintained when the AppServerELB was opened to the internet. Some threads on the internet suggest that this could be because of the `Proxy Protocol`, which adds headers to the requests sent at each stage. Thus, the AppServerELB adds its own header which in turn causes the request to be routed in an endless loop.

Questions:
1. Is the `ProxyPass` configuration above correct?
2. How do I get the ELB to not add a header?